# How to force the .xib / view to be letterboxed on iphone 5

Tags: iphone-5

As of May 1st, 2013 Apple is now requiring iPhone 5 support.  I was hoping to appease them, by simply setting the 1136 pixel tall launch image, and then having all my views be letterboxed.

Anyone have a quick way to make all my .xib and views continue to be letterboxed on the iPhone 5, even though.

Comment: what benefit is it to your users to make all your views to have black bars at the top and at the bottom on their iPhone 5's?

Comment: There is a lot of work that needs to be done in order to get the views to work correctly on the iPhone 5 and also non-iPhone screens.  I was hoping for a quick workaround in order to get the app released.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the Default.png file that has the size of the Iphone 5 width height and place the Iphone 4 size Default.png images. This will force the app to be shown letter boxed.

Also, The viceversa if you dont want to show letter boxed. i.e. stretched view for Iphone5

The best way is to use auto sizing for all the views, instead of using Auto Layout.